# Order by date not working with distinct using native query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

Currently I have a repository where I'm using a native query to find out the first 10 unique ids and these ids should be fetched with the recent ones first. To do this I'm using the following query in my repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface HomePageRepository extends JpaRepository<TransferEntity, Integer> {
    
    @Query(value="select DISTINCT transfer_to from transfers_table where transfer_from= :transfer_from ORDER BY transaction_date DESC LIMIT 10;", nativeQuery=true)
    public ArrayList<Integer> getTransferRequests(Integer transfer_from);

}
```

The following is my entity class I'm using:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "transfers_table")
public class TransferEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer Id;
    private Integer transfer_from;
    private Integer transfer_to;
    private Double transaction_amount;
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date transaction_date;
    
}
```

Now this is giving me the following error when I try to run it:

> java.sql.SQLException: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'db.transfers_table.transaction_date' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

This same query works when I remove the `Order by` clause from the statement, but then I cannot fetch the recent ids first.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. All names should be camelCase not snake_case

Comment: You can not order by a column, which is not part of the `select` clause

Comment: @Jens okay. so in this case how can I get the first 10 unique ids in `transfer_to` table but also order the output by recent first, since the newer transactions fall in the bottom of the table and this query starts fetching its output from the top

Comment: Please add sample data

Comment: @Jens This is the sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e00ee/2 . The query works in this fiddle, but not in java

Comment: wrong: It works on mysql 5.7 not on newer versions: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o8EvHHQ26cLKLAhVTyoGVU/0

Comment: As an aside don’t use `Date` in Java. It is a poorly designed and long outdated class. Consider `Instant` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: If querying transfers from 2 and there are transfers to 5 and 7 and the 5 again in the mentioned order, which of the 5s do you want included in your ordered distinct list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use subquqries:

```
select DISTINCT transfer_to from (
select transfer_to, transaction_date from transfers_table where transfer_from= 6 ORDER BY transaction_date DESC LIMIT 10
  )  as x
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o8EvHHQ26cLKLAhVTyoGVU/1)

Comment: Is the `order by` from the subquery guaranteed to enforce the same ordering in the main query?

Comment: @OleV.V. No it isnt. But per my understanding it is only interesting for the limiting